# Using AJAX and PHP to validate a simple password

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, passwords, password-protection

I have a hopefully simple problem to solve. We're trying to protect a link inside a secured part of our site with a simple password. Basically, inside our traditionally secured site, we have a dynamically driven table of records with a little padlock icon that toggles back and forth between locked and unlocked. This section of the site is already traditionally secured and accessible only to authorized users. We would therefore just like to implement this less secure static PHP password authentication system that allows users to lock and unlock records in this table. Essentially once they create a record in the table, they have the option to click the lock icon (which obviously locks the record), but only those with a simple hard coded pin can unlock a record once its locked (ie all users can lock, but not all users can unlock). I therefore tried to write a simple PHP + AJAX pin system. My other admin insisted on a server side solution. He refuses to use just basic javascript for this and I agree. It still needs a reasonable amount of security. Here is what I have so far, but I am very new (minutes) to AJAX and apparently something is not working. This is a single file named pin.php (so basically the page submits to itself)

The UNLOCK link simulates the lock icon which the user clicks to unlock the record.

```
<html>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php
    $static_password = "1234";
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        $submit_password = $_POST['data'];
        if($submit_password == $static_password){
            echo "Do the unlock stuff";
        }
        else{
            echo "Sorry try again";
        }
    }
?>
<body>
<h2>Simple AJAX PHP Example</h2>
<a href="javascript:Unlock();">UNLOCK</a>
<script>
function Unlock() {
    var pin=prompt("You must enter pin to unlock");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'pin.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {data : pin},
        success: function(response)
        { 
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: inb4 the pin gets shared because "it's annoying" and you might as well have added a button saying "are you sure you want to unlock this record".

Comment: Sorry, can you say again please? inb4?

Comment: Just something I have a feeling about that will happen once you implement above.

Comment: So do you have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: You're using `$` but I'm not seeing a `<script>` including jQuery. Plus I believe you need to move the PHP code up to the top, otherwise all the HTML up to it is also included in the AJAX response.

Comment: Hmm ok, see edit.

Comment: No change yet. Hmm

Comment: @Atomiklan, do you have errors in console ?

Comment: Nope, after the popup and pin submission, nothing seems to happen. No errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me as expected:

```
<?php
    $static_password = "1234";
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        $submit_password = $_POST['data'];
        if($submit_password == $static_password){
            die("Do the unlock stuff");
        }
        else{
            die("Sorry try again");
        }
    }
?><!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Simple AJAX PHP Example</h2>
<a href="javascript:Unlock();">UNLOCK</a>
<script>
function Unlock() {
    var pin=prompt("You must enter pin to unlock");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'pin.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {data : pin},
        success: function(response)
        { 
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm strange. Can you give a temporary public link? Maybe it's just my server?

Comment: Hmm maybe I am just missing something or it has been working the whole time. I dont see anything happening on your page either (same as mine). Can you modify the PHP to echo simple "Success" or "Failure" outputs?

Comment: Yeah something weird is still going on. I'm guessing the die commands will output their content too on quitting. I'm not seeing any of that on either of our servers. Still nothing is happening. I have tried two computers and multiple browsers.

Comment: Thank you by the way for your help with this!

Comment: Actually never used the browser console. Looking into it now. Standby

Comment: I changed it so it produces an alert() instead.

Comment: Ah ha! I see it now in the console. Perhaps I was missing the entire point of AJAX. Looks like everything is good. Let me try your new code to confirm, but I think we're there. THANK YOU!

Comment: Yup, there we go. Thank you! Marking as answer.

Comment: How to get it to alert on just failure? alert(response);

Comment: You can send back any reply you like, and on the client side, do something with it. I usually send back "done" or "fail" and simply compare the `response` to those. `if (response == "fail") ...` Or you send back a JSON string and parse it on the client side, if you want more info.